# no authentication methods available using libssh

Tags: c, libssh

Even though I can authenticate with various methods on my servers, using the libssh library, no authentication methods are detected. Here's a sample of code:

```
 #include <libssh/libssh.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int,char**)
 {
   ssh_session session = ssh_new();
   unsigned short port = 22;
   int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;

   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "localhost");
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
   ssh_connect(session);

   int supported_authentication_methods = ssh_userauth_list(session, NULL);

   printf("Supported methods: %d\n", supported_authentication_methods);
   return (0);
 }
```

And here's the output it produces:

```
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.367528, 1] ssh_connect:  libssh 0.6.4 (c) 2003-2014 Aris Adamantiadis, Andreas Schneider, and libssh contributors. Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights, using threading threads_noop
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.368626, 2] ssh_socket_connect:  Nonblocking connection socket: 5
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.368643, 2] ssh_connect:  Socket connecting, now waiting for the callbacks to work
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.368675, 1] socket_callback_connected:  Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.400420, 1] ssh_client_connection_callback:  SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.400445, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.400456, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 6.2 (60200)
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.426885, 2] ssh_packet_dh_reply:  Received SSH_KEXDH_REPLY
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.427292, 2] ssh_client_dh_reply:  SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.427311, 2] ssh_packet_newkeys:  Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
[2015/04/16 19:30:34.427908, 2] ssh_packet_newkeys:  Signature verified and valid
Supported methods: 0
```

As the output shows, no method of authentication are detected... and that's weird, because I can definitely log in to localhost, with passwords, with keys... what's up with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__auth.html#ga35d44897a44b4bb3b7c01108c1812a37):

> This requires the function [ssh_userauth_none()](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__auth.html#ga58e7c265236edbc97a2f117d3f23b4dd) to be called before the methods are available.

So call `ssh_userauth_none()` first. The server responds with the list of available options, which is how `ssh_userauth_list()` knows what to return.

```
(void)ssh_userauth_none(session, NULL);
int supported_authentication_methods = ssh_userauth_list(session, NULL);
```

Comment: Good god... and I *saw* it, I just didn't understand *why* it was there, decided not to use it, and spent the last 1h30 going left and right to fix this... thanks !

Comment: Hm... I tried to implement this properly in my program... the thing is, the documentation seems to say that `ssh_userauth_none` should return `SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS`... the fact is, despite the fact that it *does* work, that function does not return `SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS` for me... that's tricky.

Comment: I don't read the docs that way at all. Unless completely anonymous access is allowed by your server, I'd expect SSH_AUTH_DENIED or SSH_AUTH_PARTIAL

Comment: Oh. Alright, I didn't see it that way. Also... the `ssh_userauth_list` keeps telling me that I cannot log in using the login/password method (though it does accept public keys and other methods)... but all the servers I tried with do accept that method when I use the ssh client...any idea why that would happen ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea there.